Call two async methods in parallel, and display the result of each call as soon as it becomes available
I have a Maui.Net application and I need to call two methods in onAppearing in parallel (so that this is done as soon as the page is presented to the user) and display the results of each of these calls as soon as I have a response, regardless of whether I already have a response from all of them or not.
At the moment I need 2 calls, but there could be 3 in the future, so the idea is that this is versatile and creates Task/Threads according to the number of calls I may need in the future.
The methods that I need to be called in parallel have this header and will call the webservice that I developed for this application.
public static async Task<string> WCFRESTServiceCall(string methodRequestType, string methodName, string bodyParam = "")

They are usually called like this, for example:
string request = await Utils.Utils.WCFRESTServiceCall("POST", "wver", "");

In short, I need to simultaneously call my generic method that makes requests to my webservice and update the application's UI as soon as the responses arrive.
Can anyone help me implement this approach?

Sounds like a job for Task.WhenAll?

No, that's not a job for WhenAll. If anything, it's a job for WhenAny, as the OP states that the UI needs to update as soon as a response arrives for any of the tasks.

It's a shame your question got closed, especially since the "already existing" answer  is not applicable to your question. Anyway, use Task.WhenAny like this: var tasks = new List<Task> { t1, t2, t3 }; while (tasks.Any(t => !t.IsCompleted)) { var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks); tasks.Remove(completedTask); switch (completedTask) { case not null when completedTask == t1: HandleT1Result(await t1); break; ... default: throw new InvalidOperationException("Unexpected task completed."); } }. t1, t2, t3 are your calls without await (otherwise you'd get serial execution).

@BorisB. That's a horrifically bad solution.  For every single task you're adding a continuation to every single task, so that it can do something when each one finishes.  The way to do something when each of the tasks finish is to just add one continuation for each task.  And incidentally, yes, it is a situation for WhenAll, since the OP wants to wait for all of a bunch of tasks to finish.  That group is just the tasks handing the results of the original tasks.

@Servy this might be a use case for the .NET 9 Task.WhenEach.

@TheodorZoulias I wouldn't use it here, but similar implementations for it have certainly existed for a long time.

@IV unfortunately the question doesn't give us much to work with. It doesn't make clear what the two parallel calls are, nor it shows any code that displays results. Answering the question in its current state would require inventing arbitrarily all these missing pieces, which is not a great way to answer a question.

@IV you could consider casting a reopen vote. Personally I have already cast a vote previously, and so I am not allowed to vote again. The question currently linked as duplicate is not particularly relevant IMHO. This question should be either closed as "missing details", or linked to a better duplicate, or edited by the OP, improved and reopened.

@TheodorZoulias "I think that this question should be closed, which is why I reopened it, and you should to" That's certainly a take.  What do you care that the duplicate question has the exact same problem and working solutions.

@Servy I don't mind voting to reopen a question that has been closed for a wrong reason. I think that is relatively better for a question to be wrongfully open than wrongfully closed. It's the lesser of the two evils.

@TheodorZoulias Sure.  I literally couldn't imagine a question you wouldn't vote to reopen, so no surprises there.  That you think a question can't be answered doesn't deter you from voting to reopen it.  The question isn't wrongfully closed when you specifically assert that you think the question should be closed.  There's a huge difference between voting to reopen a question you think should be open, and voting to reopen a question you think should be closed.

If you think that the close reason isn't proving all of the information that the OP needs to understand how to fix their question you can help the OP better understand how to improve their question by posting a comment explaining what you think is wrong with their question that you feel needs to be improved for it to merit being open.

@Servy to help your imagination, here is a question that I wouldn't vote to reopen. Unless someone made a compelling case to reopen it, in which case I would. In any case I am not making any money by voting or not voting. I am just using my privileges as I see best, from a moral perspective. My intentions are good, and I believe that your intentions are good as well. We just have, sometimes, differing opinions about what's good. That's OK. That's why voting systems exist, to resolve differing opinions.

@TheodorZoulias Your response to seeing a question that you think should be closed was to vote to reopen it, not vote to close it for a different reason, and post a comment telling someone else to post an answer, and then tell someone else to vote to reopen it because you couldn't (again).

You didn't vote to close the question you thought should be closed, you didn't tell the OP how to improve it, you didn't find a duplicate that you thought would be better, until just now, despite the fact that there's a ton out there and clearly you could have if you had even tried, had the original state of the question really bothered you.  That sure doesn't look like good faith or "moral" behavior to me.  Your behavior doesn't even make sense given your own stated opinions.

The only opinion I see you actually expressing with your votes, is one you haven't explicitly stated, and that's your opinion that you fundamentally don't think questions should be closed, ever, and that you'll reopen any question you can, and try to find a justification later if challenged.

@Servy I'm not sure I understand why is it horrifically bad?
I tried avoiding ContinueWith, which is clunky to implement with error handling and finalization, and I wanted to avoid suggesting writing a separate async method for each task & handler.

@BorisB. The problem is you're adding N*2 continuations when you only need N.  And Task is not designed to efficiently add/remove so many continuations, so it scales particularly poorly.  Yes, ContinueWith is not going to be the most effective way of adding a continuation to the tasks, using await in an async method is going to be better for most everyone in most situations.  That's not hard to do.  Yo udon't need to define a different method for every task since they want to do the same thing for every continuation.  You only need one async method.

@Servy I don't see the N^2 anywhere, unless WaitAny is internally attaching continuations to every task in its argument list (I don't see anything in remarks or anywhere). So if I understand you correctly, you're suggesting smth like async ExecAndHandle(Task<MyResult> t) that will wrap the await and result handling, and then WaitAll on the collection of those?

@BorisB. How would you implement a method that determines when any of a list of tasks finishes without adding a continuation to each of those tasks?  If any of those tasks don't have a continuation, then you won't know when it finishes, so you can't know if it was the first to finish.  You can see a good implementation of this question in the duplicate, it's a common pattern.  There's no need for a named method, a lambda is fine, but note that if you do name it, your method claims it's executing the task, but it's not, it's just updating the UI with the results.  The task is running already.

@Servy I don't know, but I somehow doubt that it's a full-featured task continuation with all the bells and whistles. I'd assume it's something ligtweight, some valuetask-like or even a simple list of callbacks. In any case, I don't think it's quite fair to call it horrifically bad, given that the close-reason answer (at the time) missed the mark completely on what the OP was asking.

@BorisB. You can look at the source code if you want to see the specifics.  But regardless of how it adds the continuation, it's still adding the continuation.  And that means locking and other synchronization mechanisms, which is the real problem.  It's not the constructing of an object or two (that's very cheap) it's the constant locking and other inter-thread communication involved in making sure the code reliably works that's expensive.  And there are plenty of people who've run into performance problems with the technique, specifically because it is indeed very imperformant.

It's also more complex and error prone code than is needed, stemming from overcomplicating the problem.
